# Has anyone ever experienced an occasional TSAN problem?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm fixing the TSAN problem with multithreaded programs.
However, a strange phenomenon is that the TSAN warning is not generated every time running.
I want to know what causes this.

I've set up "-fsanitize=thread" and link "-ltsan"

the warning like this, but all warnings are not generated all the time. sometimes one or two, even none. I'm just repeating running and not modifying anything.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "TSAN problem"? Do you mean the **Clang thread sanitizer** tool?

Comment: What is the code that only sometimes triggers this warning?

Comment: Clang thread sanitizer tool can be used to detect TSAN problems, or directly execute the program. Just open the compilation item ”-fsanitize=thread" and link "-ltsan“.

Comment: Thread sanitizer is for finding race conditions. But race conditions are nondeterministic by definition, hence always occasional. You may increase time (amount of iterations) of testing to increase the probability of race conditions. Also you may check popular data races from TSAN: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerPopularDataRaces